# how to create a fact table from multiple dimension tables in SQL server 2008(Visual Studio 2012)?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I have four dimension tables named `Branch`, `Product`, `Supplier` and `Time`. I am taking all primary keys from these tables namely `b_id`, `p_id`, `s_id` and `quarter_id` to create my fact table. And I am adding another attribute named `total sell` based on another table named `Customer_Bill` which has `quantity`.

I want to create the fact table with data such that I get values for all the fields.
e.g. 1st branch with 3rd supplier sold 5th product in 2nd quarter and the amount is 34.

can anyone please help?

Comment: I'm sorry, Do you want to create the factTable based on real data or just ramdom data that matches your dimensions?

Comment: random data I am using. I generated the data using Mockaroo, no real data. that shouldn't matter I guess.

Comment: So the facTable should have all the combinations of Branch, Product, Supplier and Time? And what total should we use?

Comment: total would be of how many items have been sold and how much was spent. this exists in another table named customer_bill. should I link that table too?

Comment: It would help if you could post the tables you already have (structure and sample data)

Comment: where is your approach ? code or anything.

Comment: You could do worse than study Aventureworks and AventurworksDW from those clever people at Microsoft.